# Storing and retrieving large number of avatars just based on usernames?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, architecture, filesystems, scalability

I want to store large number (millions) of user avatars in the file system.
But the files must be uniformly distributed in the file system so that it scales well as more files added.

**The avatars are 5-10KB in size images.
The application is ASP.NET MVC (C#)**

Storing:

Consider these following unique user ids: bob, mike, robert, johnson
The avatar names will be bob.jog, mike.jpg, robert.jpg, johnson.jpg

HTML elements to render avatar:

```
<img class="avatar" src="www.xyz.com/getAvatar?user=bob" />
<img class="avatar" src="www.xyz.com/getAvatar?user=mike" />
```

This will go to the getAvatar controller action which will get the avatar from physical location and write to response buffer

**Current Architecture:**

```
[HttpPost]        
public ActionResult SaveAvatar(HttpPostedFile avatarImage, string user)
{
   //get MD5 hash of user (bob=9F9D51BC70EF21CA5C14F307980A29D8)
   //split MD5 hash string to get the folders (\9F\9D\51\BC\)
   //save avatar at path <file_server>\images\9F\9D\51\BC\bob.jpg
}

[HttpGet]        
public ActionResult GetAvatar(string user)
{
   //get MD5 hash of user (bob=9F9D51BC70EF21CA5C14F307980A29D8)
   //find the file location from MD5 hash (9F\9D\51\BC\)
   //return <file_server>\images\9F\9D\51\BC\bob.jpg
}
```

Am I way off on this? 
If yes, how would you architect this?

I could use the userid (auto generated as new UUID) of the user from database but in that case I have to store userid in all my tables where I have username

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen this way of creating this folder structure, however, I thought this interesting.

Assuming you will have a million of users, then you do, 1 million users X 10kb it will be something near to 10GB, it's not too much to store.

The problem is, how many users will access at the same time? If it's a lot, the server can get slow to deliver these files, because the server has to handle millions of access already.

If I had to do a website for millions of users, I wouldn't store the avatars and content in my application server, I would use a CDN(Content Delivery Network) to store the images, or even get a dedicated server for uploading images, such as avatar.mydomain.com, so I would upload to this domain via WCF.

Comment: The avatars will be stored and served from a separate server. There will be lot of access. 100s of users will access the page at the same time. I am  more concerned about the architecture than how I serve them which can be improved or changed. But changing architecture will be harder later on.

Answer (score 1):

With approach that you presented you actually end up with creating one folder structure for every avatar. And you don't have an easy way with that approach for further redistributing traffic to many servers.

In my opinion it is better to use information from unique user ids as a distribution key. For example first letter of the user id. Because thanks to that you keep your options open. Imagine that as the number of users grows you can for example split serving avatar images to two servers. `Server1` handles usernames with range `A-M` and `Server 2` handles `N-Z`. And inside that folders distributed by the first letter of user id you can use approach that you've presented.

Here is example:

```
[HttpPost]        
public ActionResult SaveAvatar(HttpPostedFile avatarImage, string user)
{
   //get MD5 hash of user (bob=9F9D51BC70EF21CA5C14F307980A29D8)
   //split MD5 hash string to get the folders (\9F\9D\51\BC\)
   //add first letter of user id to the location
   //save avatar at path <file_server>\images\b\9F\9D\51\BC\bob.jpg
}

[HttpGet]        
public ActionResult GetAvatar(string user)
{
   //get MD5 hash of user (bob=9F9D51BC70EF21CA5C14F307980A29D8)
   //find the file location from MD5 hash (9F\9D\51\BC\)
   //add first letter of user id to the location
   //return <file_server>\images\b\9F\9D\51\BC\bob.jpg
}
```

Comment: The user ids can be 3-20 characters long: a-Z0-9 and case insensitive. Bob and bob not allowed only bob or Bob. Understand you want to split first letter for servers. Then how do you distribute them in folders so that you can have somewhat even distribution. Could you provide some example? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Looks like http://serverfault.com/questions/95444/storing-a-million-images-in-the-filesystem/161014#161014 also specifies using MD5 hash as filename and directory structure